# Hypergeometric Distribution & Probability of selecting without replacement & n Percentage

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, binomial-distribution, percentages

I will ask my question through an example.

There is 100 man in N. 20 man "have card", 80 man "does not have card".

If i randomly pick 50 man, what is the percentage of "man with cards" in this 50 chosen man?

Thank you for your time & answer!

Comment: What do you mean by percentage?

Comment: more importantly, did you try anything before asking?